# React pagination component

Tags: reactjs

Its a movie search/finder, with pagination component.

The pagination currently doesn't work as aspected.

- issue: clicking the pagination the movies are always the same.

Sorry about the [codepen](https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/xxrRdZR?editors=1010), I'm new to react and I'm a bit lost.

- https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/xxrRdZR?editors=1010

  ```
  <div className="pagination-container">
  <div className="pagination-left">
    <span>{total} results found</span>
  </div>
  <div className="pagination-right">
    <div className="pagination-current">
      Page {pageNo + 1} of {maxPages}
    </div>
    <div className="pagination-buttons">
      <div className="pagination-button-wrapper">
        <button onClick={onPrev} className="pagination-button">
          &lt;
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="pagination-buttons">
      <div className="pagination-button-wrapper">
        <button onClick={onNext} className="pagination-button">
          &gt;
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem on your `useEffect`. You wrote:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  }, [pageNo]);
```

But should be:

```
useEffect(() => {
   getMovies(keyword, pageNo);
}, [pageNo, keyword]);
```

Why? Because every time you change `pageNo`, `useEffect` will be fired but if you don't pass to the function the new page value, `getMovies` will return always with films of the first page.

Then, of course, `pageNo` should start from 1:

```
const [pageNo, setPageNo] = useState(1);
```

And of course you should change this div (is not necessary to do `pageNo - 1`)

```
<div className="pagination-current">
Page {pageNo} of {maxPages}
</div>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/gioexp/pen/ZEyBZvV?editors=1010) your codepen modified.

Comment: Thank you so much, do you also know why the movie search doesn't work anymore? If I search for batman for instance...

Comment: @user173420 yes because I didn't see that you search also for `keywork`. I updated answer and codepen. Check if it's correct and let me know =)

Comment: @user173420 I'm checking right now. I will update you soon.

Comment: @user173420 the prev button has an incorrect `disabled` prop. You wrote `disabled={pageNo === 0}` but with my changes, now `pageNo` starts from 1. So just change the prev button in this way: `<button onClick={onPrev} className="pagination-button" disabled={pageNo === 1}>` and problem disappears. [Here](https://codepen.io/gioexp/pen/KKqavNZ) the new codepen.

Comment: @user173420 No I didn't check. Give me more time and I will update you =)

Comment: @user173420 no sorry. If you have no more time to wait, post another question. I think someone could help you faster than me. Sorry again

Comment: Gio, I had some progress but I have some more bugs. For some reason now it shows no mpre that 10 items https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/dyRvvWB?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

Just use `react-bhx-pagination` to do this easily passing a json or the endpoint. Everything will work

Repo: [react-bhx-pagination](https://github.com/coffezilla/react-bhx-pagination)

Example: [Online Demo](https://react-bhx-pagination.netlify.app/)